# Can i convert my code in a global enviroment variable?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file, environment-variables

I made this code to be able to easily move a directory between my SSD and HD and also output a timestamp in my robocopy log files easily, it worked so well that i want to turn my timestamp &z& variable into a global variable so that i can use it to output logfiles with this timestamp when i use a command line like this:

```
"File Organizer.bat" > C:\Logs\log%z%.log 2>&1
```

So that the log file generated will look like this:

```
log_05.10.2021_02.55.log
```

My robocopy batch file is below:

```
cls
Color 03

@echo off

:: Adapting timestamps for use in file formats
:: Change the z set to fit your locale

set t=%date%_%time%
set z=%t:~0,2%.%t:~3,2%.%t:~6,4%_%t:~11,2%.%t:~14,2%
set z=%z: =0%

:: Setting Variables
:: Change the variables to fit your needs

set _source="C:\Folder01"

set _dest="D:\Folder02"

set _opt=/E /MOVE /R:2 /W:1

SET _log=/LOG:"D:\ROOT\Logs\log_%z%.txt" /TEE /NP

@echo.
@echo *******************************************************************************
@echo #                                                                             
@echo # This CMD moves a folder to another place and makes a Symbolic link to it
@echo #                                                                             
@echo # Robocoping %_source%  
@echo #                                                                             
@echo # to %_dest%
@echo #                                                                             
@echo # With Parameters %_opt%
@echo #                                                                             
@echo # Logging %_log%
@echo #                                                                             
@echo *******************************************************************************
@echo.
pause

:: Creating Destination Directory

MD %_dest%

:: Moving/Copying the files/folders

ROBOCOPY %_source% %_dest% %_opt% %_log%

:: Creating Symbolic Link

MKLINK /D %_source% %_dest%

@echo.
@echo *******************************************************************************
@echo #                                                                             
@echo # Job Completed...
@echo #                                                                             
@echo *******************************************************************************
@echo.

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run another batch file to set up your environment variables first.

Copy out your date lines into a new batch file, for example `LogDate.bat`:

```
set t=%date%_%time%
set z=%t:~0,2%.%t:~3,2%.%t:~6,4%_%t:~11,2%.%t:~14,2%
set z=%z: =0%
setx z %z%
```

Then you should be able to run that before the rest of your command

```
LogDate.bat && "File Organizer.bat" > C:\Logs\log%z%.log 2>&1
```

Comment: That did not work. Log file output is "log%z%.log" also, i want the z variable to become global variable, cant i do that with setx somehow?

Comment: Is the `LogDate.bat` file in the same directory as `File Organiser.bat`? How are you running it? I suspect that the `LogDate.bat` file is not being found. I've just added the `setx` command as above and after running `LogDate.bat` on it's own and opening a new command prompt it has the value z correctly for me. (my output is garbled because I use ISO date format, but is otherwise achieves your requirement)

Comment: so sorry to say, but is not working **[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059311/how-do-i-retrieve-a-value-after-using-setx/46598447#46598447)**

Answer (score 0):

- In `Search`, search for and then select: `System (Control Panel)`
- Click the `Advanced system settings` link.
- Click `Environment Variables`. In this section, you can set user or computer wide variables that will always be active.

Answer (score 0):

- Considering, or remembering...

> **[Because SETX writes variables to the master environment in the registry, edits will only take effect when a new command window is opened - they do not affect the current CMD or PowerShell session.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24060861/8177207)**

Call your bat, if no arguments were passed, define your variables and call your bat again (by themselves), this time passing them already redirecting to the log file with the desired name, defined and with current date/time...

```bath
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1"=="" (

     color 03
     mode 100,27
     
     cd /d "%~dp0"
     
     set "_sources=C:\Folder01"
     set "_destiny=D:\Folder02"
     
     set "_opt=/E /MOVE /R:2 /W:1"
     set "_log=/LOG:"D:\ROOT\Logs\!!_log!!.txt" /TEE /NP"
     
     for /f %%i in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime^|find "."')do set _dt=%%i
     set "_log=log_!_dt:~6,2!_!_dt:~4,2!_!_dt:~0,4!_!_dt:~8,2!_!_dt:~10,2!"
     
     echo\ Outputs Files: Log %~nx0 !_log!.log ^& RoboCopy.exe "!_log!.txt" 
     
     call "%~f0" "!_sources!" "!_destiny!" "!_opt!" "!_log!.txt" >"!_log!.log"
     
     exit /b )else endlocal

echo\
echo\ ********************************************************************************
echo\ #                                                                             
echo\ # This CMD moves a folder to another place and makes a Symbolic link to it
echo\ #                                                                             
echo\ # Robocoping %~1
echo\ #                                                                             
echo\ # to %~2
echo\ #                                                                             
echo\ # With Parameters %~3
echo\ #                                                                             
echo\ # Logging %~4
echo\ #                                                                             
echo\ ********************************************************************************

mkDir %~2

:: Moving/Copying the files/folders

RoboCopy %~1 %~2 %~3 %~4

:: Creating Symbolic Link

mkLink /D %~1 %~2 

echo\
echo\ ********************************************************************************
echo\ #                                                                             
echo\ # Job Completed...
echo\ #                                                                             
echo\ ********************************************************************************
```

---

- Outputs in the `log_11_10_2021_12_53.log` file:

```bath
 ********************************************************************************
 #                                                                             
 # This CMD moves a folder to another place and makes a Symbolic link to it
 #                                                                             
 # Robocoping C:\Folder01
 #                                                                             
 # to D:\Folder02
 #                                                                             
 # With Parameters /E /MOVE /R:2 /W:1
 #                                                                             
 # Logging log_11_10_2021_12_53.txt
 #                                                                             
 ********************************************************************************
 mkDir D:\Folder02
 RoboCopy C:\Folder01 D:\Folder02 /E /MOVE /R:2 /W:1 log_11_10_2021_12_53.txt
 mkLink /D C:\Folder01 D:\Folder02 

 ********************************************************************************
 #                                                                             
 # Job Completed...
 #                                                                             
 ********************************************************************************
```

**Obs.:** There is no need to define the system variable for this task, nor how to update its value at runtime, there is a lot of command involved to compose the layout of the name and I cannot say that it is possible to port to a single line/variable that can be used in the same session with Real-Time update of values/strings...